Optimal bet using the Kelly criterion if the odds and probability update.
I'm wondering about how to change the bets given that our information about the probability and odds may change throughout the event.
For example, let's say we have \$100 to bet, and there is an event with a 10% probability of occurring with decimal odds 13.0. The Kelly criterion says we should bet $0.1 - \frac{0.9}{12} = 0.025$ as a proportion of our starting money, so \$2.5. So we place this bet.
Now, throughout the event, the our information updates. The probability of winning increases to 20%, and the bookmaker offers new odds of 6.0. The same calculation gives that we should bet \$4 on this.
Now, it's tempting to say that we should stake another \$1.5 on the new bet at these odds, but I don't think this is exactly correct. One mistake might be that we should use \$97.5 as our new amount to bet, but even then my gut feeling is that this isn't optimal as the outcome of this event is dependent on the previous event. My idea is if the odds continually change throughout an event, and this idea would have us bet far too often on the same event.
That being said, I find it really hard to extend the derivation of Kelly's criterion to this situation, because the proof depends on the independence of each bet. So I'm lost at how to figure this out.

You are correct when you say you would stake another $1.5. Kelly Criterion tells you how much risk you are willing to take given the current odds. It doesn't matter what odds you placed the original wager at, you just need to make sure that the sum of all of your wagers is equal to what Kelly Criterion says. This is contingent on it being the exact same event and not independent trials of course though.
